# Why is git ignoring some folders?

Tags: git

wait, what? I don't want to ignore this.

I was working on a project, when I tried to create an `Icon` folder I have noticed that git is ignoring this latter and everything inside it at first I thought it could be something suspicious inside the black hole aka node_modules. so I did go to `Desktop` folder and initiate a new empty project but no hope too, check the screenshot below you will find much more explanation.

[image]

so yeah I don't want to ignore that folder.

Comment: Git tracks content.  Put something in that folder and GIt will care. ... oh. right. See @ElpieKay's answer.

Comment: @jthill I have index.js inside it

Comment: Do you have a global gitignore file?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth nope, but I got the one that automatically created by GitHub for Mac, after looking at it there is an `Icon` folder so I think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS, you can assign a custom icon to any folder. If you do this (or if someone else does this in a package you download), it shows up as a file in the folder which is named `Icon\r` (sometimes displays as `Icon?` or `Icon^M`). This is the word `Icon` followed by a CR (carriage return) character.

People often want to ignore these in git, so it's not uncommon to see it in gitignore files. Unfortunately it is often done wrong. Sometimes people use something like this:

```
Icon
Icon*
```

The first won't work, and the second will catch anything starting with `Icon`.

You may have something like that going on here.

Github supplies a default macOS gitignore file, which you can find here:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/macOS.gitignore

If you grab the raw version of that file, either using the "Raw" button, or by cloning the repository, you would get the version containing the `\r` character in the filename. But if you copy/paste from the above URL, it will only have `Icon` and thus not work properly. That is another thing that might have happened here.

Answer (score 3):

To list the ignored folders/files,

```
git status --ignored
```

To add the ignored folders/files,

```
git add -f <path>
```

If you commit these folders/files, they will not be ignored even if they are in the ignored list.

To check where the ignored folders/files are specified,

```
git check-ignore -v <path>
```

You could remove the ignored patterns from the configuration.

As @jthill notes, Git can't track empty folders. You must put at least one file in it. It could be an empty file.

Comment: The OP has a file in that folder.